# how to open a url in ios child browser using Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Can any one please let me know how to open child browser using titanium for IOS.
I have used, `Titanium.Platform.openURL(url);` but it is opening out of the application and can't come back to our app after closing the window/tab.Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance,
Swathi

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WebView for that. Have a look at the API:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView

there is an example how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I tried with this but I am not getting any close button or anything else to quit from that window and get back to our app. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: A webview is just as a view you can use anywhere in your app. Include your `webview` inside a window that you can close to get back to the previous opened window in your app.

Comment: Is it possible to open a child browser rather than a web view because in that there is an option to print that page as I am opening a pdf url. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: a webview is just a childbrowser as you expect it. However, you can just download a ready browser. Just look at gitt.io and find the open source browser that suits your needs: http://gitt.io/search?q=browser

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a SafariDialog described here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.SafariDialog

Add the module like so:

```
<ti:app>
  ...
  <modules>
    <module platform="iphone">ti.safaridialog</module>
  </modules>
  ...
</ti:app>
```

And use it like so:

```
var dialog = require('ti.safaridialog');

if (dialog.isSupported()) {
    dialog.open({
        url: 'http://appcelerator.com',
        title: 'Titanium rocks!',
        tintColor: 'red'
    });
}
```

This also adds the "Done" button you were looking for.